# Intersection of sets and its cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a certain exercise I am asked to find how many subsets of $A = \{1 \dots 30 \}$ are there such that its intersection with $B = \{1,2,3 \}$ and with $C = \{ 29,30 \}$ is non-empty. I have tried it and I think I reached a successful answer, however, I would like that my answer was confirmed. Here is my approach:

To begin with, if I fix an element of $C$, for the set $B$, I use inclusion-exclusion principle: the cardinal of the set of subsets of $A$ with non-empty intersection with $B$ is obtained by fixing one of $3$ elements in $B$ and obtaining another $2^{28} - 1$ subsets (without counting the empty set). However, if I decide to choose two elements fixed, there are $3$ options to do that, and another possible $2^{27} - 1$ subsets. For fixing all elements in $B$, there are $2^{26} - 1$ subsets remaining. Therefore, using inclusion exclusing I have $3\cdot 2^{28} - 3\cdot 2^{27} + 2^{26} - 1$ possible sets taking into account the intersection between a subset and $B$. I can fix two elements of $C$, so for the moment it would be $2 \cdot that \ quantity$. Now, if there are the two elements of $C$ fixed in the intersection, then using the same reasoning would be $3 \cdot 2^{27} - 3 \cdot 2^{26} + 2^{25} - 1$

Using again inclusion-exclusion, the final answer would be the first final term minus the second final term since I have counted twice all the cases in which both $29,30$ appear. Is this correct? By the way, if I just wanted to know the intersection of subsets and $B$, is my reasoning right?

Comment: There’s an easier way to do this. Take the total number of subsets of $A$, then subtract the number of subsets of the set difference $A-B$, then subtract the subsets of $A-C$, then add back in the subsets of $A-(B\cup C)$.

Comment: That is also an interesting approach. However, is my attempt right?

Comment: I want to add that what @MikeEarnest is describing is known as the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: My final answer would be $3\cdot 2^{28}-6\cdot 2^{27}+4\cdot 2^{26}-2^{25}$. I also used inclusion-exclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect, because you made one mistake.

> the cardinal of the set of subsets of $A$ with non-empty intersection with $B$ is obtained by fixing one of $3$ elements in $B$ and obtaining another $2^{28} - 1$ subsets (without counting the empty set).

You should not only be counting nonempty subsets at this stage. The correct number here should be $2^{28}$. If you make that change in your solution, you should get the correct answer. You may want to try correcting your solution yourself using this hint, and then confirming your answer using the full solution below.

---

Fix an element $c_0$ of $C$. We first count how many subsets specifically contain $c_0$, along with some element of $B$. Let $S_1$ be the number of subsets which contain $c_0$ and which contain $1\in B$. Similarly, define $S_2$ and $S_3$. You want to find $|S_1\cup S_2 \cup S_3|$, which is handled by inclusion exclusion.

- $|S_1|=|S_2|=|S_3|=2^{28}$. This is your first mistake; you had $2^{28}-1$ here, but there is no reason to require nonempty subsets.
- $|S_1\cap S_2|=|S_1\cap S_3|=|S_2\cap S_3|=2^{27}$. For example, for $|S_1\cap S_2|$, you know the subset contains $c_0,1,$ and $2$, but the other $27$ elements of $A$ can be freely added or not.
- $|S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3|=2^{26}$.

All in all, the number of subsets which contain $c_0$, and at least one element of $B$, are
$$
3\cdot 2^{28}-3\cdot 2^{27}+2^{26}
$$
Now, define $T_{29}$ to be the set of subsets which contain $29$ *and* at least one element of $B$. Similarly, let $T_{30}$ be the number of subsets which contain $30$, *and* at least one element of $B$. The previous work implies
$$
|T_{29}|=|T_{30}|=3\cdot 2^{28}-3\cdot 2^{27}+2^{26}
$$
Similarly, you can show that
$$
|T_{29}\cap T_{30}|=3\cdot 2^{27}-3\cdot 2^{26}+2^{25}
$$
Since the final answer to your problem is $|T_{29}\cup T_{30}|=|T_{29}|+|T_{30}|-|T_{29}\cap T_{30}|$, we get
$$
2\cdot (3\cdot 2^{28}-3\cdot 2^{27}+2^{26})-(3\cdot 2^{27}-3\cdot 2^{26}+2^{25})
=6\cdot 2^{28}-9\cdot 2^{27}+5\cdot 2^{26}-2^{25}
$$
for the final answer.